# select rows in mysql having another column with same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that manage conversations of a chat between users, the structure is the following.

```
id | user_id | conversation_id
```

let's say that on the conversation with ID 1 there are 3 people to chat and the conversation with ID 2, 2 people as well

Conversations_users table will look like this

```
   id | user_id | conversation_id
    1      1              1
    2      2              1
    3      4              1
    4      3              2
    5      4              2
```

Now having only the id of the users `3` and `4` and **Not Conversation ID** I would like select the conversation that belongs to that users so a verbal query should be:

`Select from conversations_users, where in user_id = 3 and 4 and conversation_id is equals to conversation id of user 3 and 4`

how can I build this "verbal query" in Mysql?

Comment: looks like it has a surrogate key as well as two data columns to me.

Comment: @Strawberry Yhea i forgot to add the ID key.

Comment: @OllieJones what do you mean? :)

Comment: An autoincremented id column is sometimes called a surrogate primary key.

Comment: what do you want to 'select' i.e., the user_id or the conversation_id ? also, do you want only the conversations that have both users 3 and 4, or do you want the conversations that have either user 3 or user 4? [ie, from this result set do you want only conversation 2, or both conversation 1 and 2?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select uc.conversation_id
from UserConversions uc
where uc.user_id in (3, 4)
group by uc.conversation_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If the table could have duplicates, you'll want:  `having count(distinct user_id) = 2`.

EDIT:

If you want a specific list, just move the `where` condition to the `having` clause:

```
select cu.conversation_id
from conversations_users cu
group by cu.conversation_id
having sum(cu.user_id in (3, 4)) = 2 and
       sum(cu.user_id not in (3, 4)) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, really appreciated. I'll try it now and I'll let you know :)

Comment: @Fabrizio . . . How did it not work?  I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer to your question.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36b49/2 see the jsfiddle it should select only the conversation between user `3,4` but that query select even the conversation between `1,2,3,4` if I want to check that the users 3,4 has a conversation it shouldn't select the conversation with 1,2,3,4. Your query select all the conversations that that user belongs to. Looking forward to find a solution :)

Comment: forget about the link of sqlfiddle of before I did mistake to create the table but this one is right and I used your last query see the result it is a bit strange. Thanks a lot for your help if we can solve it will be really great. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e2b/1

Comment: Do you know that YOU HAVE A BRILLIANT MIND!! IT WORKS PERFECT!!! the only thing I would like ask you is the 0 value after the `AND` will never change I'm right?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e2b/14

Simply with 1 query, It's amazing Thanks a lots!!!

Comment: @Fabrizio . . . The `0` will never change, if you are looking for conversations among a specific group of users with no others.  If you allowed one other, then it would be `<= 1`.  The `2` does change depending on the length of the list used with `in`.

Comment: Do you know that i was really stuck on that from days I'm so happy that you help me. And thanks for your last explanation all clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

to get all the users in the conversations that user 3 and 4 are part of you could use this:

```
select distinct(user_id) from conversation_table where conversation_id in (select distinct(conversation_id) from conversation_table where user_id in (3,4));
```

it won't be very fast though

to get their actual conversations, I'm assuming you have a different table with the text in it:

you probably want something like this

```
select distinct(u.user_id), c.text from conversation_table u left join conversations c on c.id=u.conversation_id where u.conversation_id in (select distinct(conversation_id) from conversation_table where user_id in (3,4));
```

here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63cb3/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot it seem to work seeing your sqlfiddle, do you think doing that sub query may slow down to much checking the table with a lots rows?

Comment: yeah, they slow down quite a lot, you just have to choose where to put indexes properly, for that table, Id put them on user_id and conversation_id, and also make the conversation_id a foreign key to the conversation table.

Comment: mmmh, If I probably do a pivot table with key constraint on conversation_id that point to conversation table and same for user_id on id of user table? Or there is any chance that I may find another solution more efficient even changing the structure? Really appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have another table called "conversations" which holds the data you really want.

```
SELECT *
FROM conversations, conversations_users
WHERE conversations_users.user_id in (3,4)
    AND conversations.id = conversations_users.conversation_id
```

Comment: Yhea i have that table, I'll give a try even to this one, Thanks a lot

Comment: `select * from conversations join conversations_users on (conversations.id = conversations_users.conversation_id) where conversations_users.user_id in (3,4)`

Comment: @PaulTomblin thanks for the query but it get 2 different results see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e2b/6 it should only the conversation of user 3 and 4

Comment: I'm just re-writing rcoty's query in more modern syntax. It gets the same results as his.

Comment: @PaulTomblin please feel free to make your comment a new answer.  The indents can make SQL easier to read.

Comment: I'm not going to make it an answer because it doesn't exactly answer the question - if finds any conversation that includes either of the two people, not just conversations that only include those two people.